# How to use query parameters in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am a freshman in Nest.js.

And my code as below

```
  @Get('findByFilter/:params')
  async findByFilter(@Query() query): Promise<Article[]> {

  }
```

I have used `postman` to test this router

http://localhost:3000/article/findByFilter/bug?google=1&baidu=2

Actually, I can get the query result `{ google: '1', baidu: '2' }`. But I'm not clear why the url has a string `'bug'`?

If I delete that word just like

http://localhost:3000/article/findByFilter?google=1&baidu=2

then the postman will shows statusCode `404`.

Actually, I don't need the word `bug`, how to custom the router to realize my destination just like `http://localhost:3000/article/findByFilter?google=1&baidu=2`

Here's another question is how to make mutiple router point to one method?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

#### Query parameters

You have to remove `:params` for it to work as expected:

```
@Get('findByFilter')
async findByFilter(@Query() query): Promise<Article[]> {
  // ...
}
```

---

#### Path parameters

The `:param` syntax is for path parameters and matches any string on a path:

```
@Get('products/:id')
getProduct(@Param('id') id) {
```

matches the routes

```
localhost:3000/products/1
localhost:3000/products/2abc
// ...
```

---

#### Route wildcards

To match multiple endpoints to the same method you can use route wildcards:

```
@Get('other|te*st')
```

will match

```
localhost:3000/other
localhost:3000/test
localhost:3000/te123st
// ...
```

Answer (score 79):

If you have you parameter as part or url:   */articles/${articleId}/details*, you wold use @Param

```
@Get('/articles/:ARTICLE_ID/details')
async getDetails(
    @Param('ARTICLE_ID') articleId: string
)
```

IF you want to provide query params */article/findByFilter/bug?**google=1&baidu=2***, you could use

```
@Get('/article/findByFilter/bug?')
async find(
    @Query('google') google: number,
    @Query('baidu') baidu: number,
)
```

Answer (score 16):

We can use @Req()

```
import { Controller, Get, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

(...)

@Get(':framework')
getData(@Req() request: Request): Object {
    return {...request.params, ...request.query};
}
```

/nest?version=7

```
{
    "framework": "nest",
    "version": "7"
}
```

[read more](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object)

Comment: I had to put this code...

import { Request } from 'express';

...on top of the script for this to work!

Comment: @JonathanMartins Feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score 5):

**For common case:**

```
getSomeDataRoute(@Query() allQueryParams: { search?: string, page?: string })

// or

getSomeDataRoute(@Query('search') search?: string, @Query('page') page?: string)
```

**For advanced case** with dto and transformer:

```
class QueryDto {
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    public readonly page: number;

    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    public readonly take: number;
}

@Injectable()
class QueryTransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
    async transform(value: QueryRequestDto, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
        if (!metatype) {
            return value;
        }

        return plainToInstance(metatype, value);
    }
}


@Controller()
class YourController {
    @Get()
    // also you can use it with pipe decorator
    // @UsePipes(new QueryTransformPipe())
    async getData(@Query(new QueryTransformPipe()) query?: QueryRequestDto) {
        // here you get instanceof QueryTransformPipe
        // with typeof query.page === 'number' && typeof query.take === 'number'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@Req` decorator, and use param object, see :

```
@Get()
  findAll(
    @Req() req: Request
  ): Promise<any[]> {
    console.log(req.query);
    // another code ....
  }
```

Comment: No need to do this, Nest helps you by abstracting a lot of the underlying Express request away:
https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object

Comment: Actually might help when you are creating a proxy and want to transfer the params as is