# How to get parameters out of Query in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to be able to get a license plate from my query parameters, but it doesn't seem to work, whatever way I write my code, so I'm getting quite confused why it's not working.

Here's the expected behaviour: when using the following GET request: `http://localhost:3978/licenseplate/getleasingcompany?licenseplate=1-WMW-478`
I want to extract the licenseplate parameter.

Here's my current code:

```
@Get('getleasingcompany')
async getLeasingCompany(@Query('licenseplate') licenseplate: string) {
    console.log(licenseplate);
}
```

This logs `licenseplate` as `undefined` when trying in postman.

I also tried variants of this code, such as:

```
@Get('getleasingcompany')
async getLeasingCompany(@Query() query) {
    console.log(query);
}
```

This logged `query` as `[Function: getQuery]`, which I have no idea how to handle (`query.licenseplate` is `undefined`)

Another option is found in a Stackoverflow explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958244/how-to-use-query-parameters-in-nest-js), in which Kim uses path parameters. This did work for me, but isn't behaviour my program can use, unfortunately.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT 1: After a few comments, I updated my packages to version 7.1.2, to no avail. Returning the `query` to postman gives following output:

```
function getQuery() {
// always return a string, because this is the raw query string.
// if the queryParser plugin is used, req.query will provide an empty
// object fallback.
return this.getUrl().query || '';
}
```

EDIT 2: Tried going the Express route by importing `Request` as follows: `import { Request } from "express";`. The code now looks like this:

```
@Get('getleasingcompany')
  async getLeasingCompany(@Req() request: Request) {
    console.log(request);
}
```

A part of this log does show me that the query saved the variable:

```
originalUrl: '/licenseplate/getleasingcompany?licenseplate=1-WMW-478',
  _parsedUrl:
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: '?licenseplate=1-WMW-478',
     query: 'licenseplate=1-WMW-478',
     pathname: '/licenseplate/getleasingcompany',
     path: '/licenseplate/getleasingcompany?licenseplate=1-WMW-478',
     href: '/licenseplate/getleasingcompany?licenseplate=1-WMW-478',
     _raw: '/licenseplate/getleasingcompany?licenseplate=1-WMW-478' },
```

However, when logging the `request.query`, I still get `[Function: GetQuery]` as the result.

Comment: Where is `@Query()` being imported from? Is it by chance from `@nestjs/graphql`? And are your nest common, core, and platform packages on the same version?

Comment: It's all imported from Common. `import { Controller, Get, Body, HttpException, Post, Query } from "@nestjs/common";`. Except for typeORM, they're all on version 6.7.2, typeORM is on 7.0.0

Comment: Do you have some reproduction of this?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot share the files due to them being related to my work. I have however found a 'solution', which i'll share in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found why the program didn't work as intended, I have however fixed the issue simply by starting a new Nest project. When I noticed this project did work as intended, I copied over all the files except for package.json and reinstalled all the necessary dependencies one by one. I only deleted 1 dependency, `restify`, which I ended up not needing. It worked with the package though, so that wasn't the issue.

Due to these findings, I suppose it must have been a versioning issue, though I'm still not sure.

Comment: Looks like somehow the resitfy request is what was being used, which is why query became the `getQuery()` function. Not really sure how that happened without seeing what was going on in `main.ts`, but glad you got it resolved.

Comment: Thanks for helping me look into the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing looks wrong in your code. On Nest v7 using the following controller and curl I get what you'd expect

```js
import { Controller, Get, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(@Query() query: Record<string, any>): string {
    console.log(query);
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

```sh
curl http://localhost:3000/\?queryparam\=something
```

```sh
[Nest] 46471   - 06/02/2020, 2:55:11 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 46471   - 06/02/2020, 2:55:11 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +12ms
[Nest] 46471   - 06/02/2020, 2:55:11 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +15ms
[Nest] 46471   - 06/02/2020, 2:55:11 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {, GET} route +9ms
[Nest] 46471   - 06/02/2020, 2:55:11 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +9ms
{ queryparam: 'something' }
```

My only guess is some mismatched version of Nest

Comment: I updated all Nest packages to latest (7.1.2 for common, core and platform), to no avail. Using your getHello function, the query log says `[Function: getQuery]`, when I return it, postman gives me the following: `function getQuery() {
// always return a string, because this is the raw query string.
// if the queryParser plugin is used, req.query will provide an empty
// object fallback.
return this.getUrl().query || '';
}`

Comment: Are you using Fastify or Express?

Comment: @nestjs/platform-express:"7.1.2"